# Call function from deployed contract

Tags: contract-invocation, transferfrom, eth-call

I have a deployed contract (**contract A**) which should act as a storage (let's say 0xD7ACd2a9FD159E69Bb102A1ca21C9a3e3A5F771B).

Now from my ERC20 Token contract (**contract B**), I am calling approve to the **contract A** to allow it to "withdraw" my tokens.

Would it be possible to call trasnferFrom of contract A inside another function of contract B?

I am trying with (inside the code of B)

```
address A = 0xD7ACd2a9FD159E69Bb102A1ca21C9a3e3A5F771B;
...
approve(A,_amount);
A.call(bytes4(keccak256("transferFrom(address, address, uint256)")), (_B, msg.sender, _amount));
```

But it doesn't work since I am giving too many arg to the call function.

What would be the best way to transfer automatically my token (contract A) to a deployed ERC20 contract from within the contract B itslef?

**EDIT**

So on my receiver contract A, I added the function:

```
    function getTokens (address from, uint256 value) public returns (bool) {
        transferFrom(from, address(this), value);
        return true;
    }
```

And on my sender contract B I am calling:

```
    address contract_address = 0x09943Fa8DD32C76f7b880627a0F6af73e8f5A595 ;
     
...
        approve(contract_address, _value);
        contract_address.call(abi.encode("getTokens(address, uint256)",msg.sender, _value));
...
```

But even if tx is succesfull, when I check balance of contract A, it's 0.
I don't know exactly what I am missing.

Comment: Are you sure you are checking `balanceOf` and not just `balance`?

Comment: Yes I am calling
    function balanceOf(address account) public view override returns (uint256) {
        return _balances[account];
    }
with the contract address as argument, but still balance is 0

Comment: I am having a doubt: since the two contract that interacts are deployed on VM (Remix), should the address variable or some of the inputs of the functions be indicated as memory? Cause If i check allowance on Contract B it's correct, but if I try to call "tranferFrom" from contract A, it doesn't work cause "value exceed balance".

Comment: Hi @4NDR34, Have you find any solution of this. I have the exactly the same problem. Any information would be of great help.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure I understood your scenario correctly, but let's try to answer.

No you can't "push" tokens with `transferFrom`. That function needs to be called by the contract / EOA which wants to get the tokens (and has allowance to withdraw).

If you want to push tokens you can use the `transfer` function, but that has different semantics, as you probably know.

What you can do is add functionality in whatever contract wants the tokens, for example a new function `getTheTokens`. That function could then be called by whatever other contract and that function calls the `transferFrom`.